# Setting value to textview in android

Tags: android, textview

How to assign a value to a textview?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
    android:text = "@string/hName"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the structure of one of the views I am creating. Now I want to assign value which comes from the previous activity to hname .I am able to get it from the previous activity but I am not able to set it to the textview. When I use setText(), it shows null pointer exception. How can I assign value to that text field. Thanks in advance.

This is the corresponding java code.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String host_name = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectionsActivity.HOST_NAME);
    TextView tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hName);
    tvName.setText(host_name);
    setContentView(R.layout.sharedfiles);
```

Comment: Not clear: hname belongs to the previous activity?

Comment: Almost certain that findViewById returned null, which means you used the wrong id or called it before setting the content view, or you forgot to call it at all.

Comment: Move `setContentView(R.layout.sharedfiles);` to the top

Comment: I already tried that. It shows same error. The error is in line of setText. If I comment that line it doesn't show any errors. I think tvName is null.

Comment: post your previous activity startActivity method. Are you sure that previous activity is adding that EXTRA to the intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem with your structure..

its giving you a null-pointer exception because it can't find text-view...

put `setContentView(R.layout.sharedfiles);` above intent...

try this..

```
setContentView(R.layout.sharedfiles);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String host_name = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectionsActivity.HOST_NAME);
TextView tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hName);
tvName.setText(host_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

@string/hName is accesible everywhere in your application code by

```
getString(R.string.hName);
```

The null exception comes from something else, you'd better to post your logcat.